# urlConnection.getOutputStream get stuck

Tags: java, node.js

I'm trying to build java application which post data to node.js server.

The code which handle the post in the node.js looks:

```
app.post('/login.html', function (req, res) {

    log.info(req.body);
    userName = req.body.name;
    pass = req.body.pass;
    ...
}
```

The java application looks:

```
URL url;

HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
try {
    url = new URL("http://86.61.133.223/login.html:39083");

    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

    OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();          
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("name", "root");
    parameters.put("pass", "123456");

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));          
    writer.write(getParamsString(parameters));
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();         

}
```

for unknown reason , I'm getting stuck on:

```
OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
```

In the node.js I didn't notice for any connection attempt.

So, why I'm getting stuck, and how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `39083` should be the port (what i think) your URL is worng. port belongs to the hostname not to the URI:

```
url = new URL("http://86.61.133.223:39083/login.html");
```